# How to convert Adobe Premiere Elements 12 file to some other program that renders faster?

Tags: video, video-editing, adobe-premiere

Yesterday, I used Adobe Premiere Elements 12 for the first time. I spent hours and hours carefully editing a video that is 30 mins long.

Then, when I went to render (export) it to 1920x1080 30fps mp4 file, it said it would take **3 hours** to export.

So then I tried exporting to Flash video instead. The rendering was faster but still unacceptably slow.

My computer is new and fast (Intel Core i7 6700K 4.0Ghz 8MB Cache Quad-Core, 16GB RAM, 1TB SSD, 4GB GeForce GTX 970 GDDR5).

After searching around online, it seems that *tons* of people are disappointed in Adobe Premiere's rendering speeds.

How could I convert my `.prel` project file to be used in some *other* video editing software (so that I salvage all of my editing work)... or... somehow drastically improve the rendering speed of Premiere?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a lot of a computer to do it all at once. Split the job into two passes.

Export to a high bitrate professional codec first (ProRes or Cineform perhaps). Then convert that using Handbrake or similar to an h264 complaint file.

3 hours for a 30 minute video however isn't too bad. There's lots of work involved in converting between codecs, and reexporting an encoded file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think I'm "asking a lot of a computer", especially since using Adobe Premiere Pro (instead of Elements) takes only *minutes* for an export to h264 (instead of hours). I've been using Premiere Pro ever since posting this question and will never go back to Elements. But I wish I could export that Elements project in a way that was usable by Pro.